# Feeding data to keras bottleneck in a non-sequential graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am attempting to do some experimentation with a neural network involving feeding custom data into its bottleneck layer and analyzing the output.

It's likely I'm going about this the wrong way. My belief is that, using keras, the only way to achieve custom bottleneck inputs is to have the model be made of two smaller models. I would train the large model on my training data, and then call predict() on the second smaller model with whatever bottleneck vector for analysis.

Unfortunately, my first model is not sequential (I could maybe merge Image1 and Image2 into a 2-channel image, but I have a feeling there's an easier/more generalizable solution). So making a third model using Sequential.add() is out of the question.

```py
def image_input_model_3(hidden_units=11):
    im1 = Input(shape=(size,size),name='Image1')
    im2 = Input(shape=(size,size),name='Image2')
    input1 = Input(shape=(hidden_units,))

    def model1():
        flat1 = Reshape([size*size],name='Flat1')(im1)
        flat2 = Reshape([size*size],name='Flat2')(im2)
        concat = Concatenate()([flat1,flat2])
        out = Dense(units=(hidden_units))(concat)
        return Model([im1,im2],out,name='im2vec')

    def model2():
        out1 = Dense(units=(9*size*size))(input1)
        out2 = Reshape([9,size,size], name='Reshape')(out1)
        out3 = Softmax(axis=1, name='Softmax2')(out2)
        return Model([input1], out3, name='vec2trans')

    input_model = model1()([im1,im2])
    output_model = model2()([input_model])
    model3 = Model([im1,im2],output_model)

    return input_model, output_model, model3
```

The above code runs, but input_model and output_model are now Tensor objects and not Models, so I can't run predict() upon them.

How do I construct this in a way that I can call predict on all three models, or otherwise how should I approach the custom bottleneck problem with a non-sequential graph?

Comment: You're already passing [im1, im2] as parameters into Model. Why are you calling model1 as follows? `model1()([im1,im2])`

Comment: Otherwise the line immediately afterwards creates an error: "Layer vec2trans was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor."

Is there a simple way to create these models and still use them as components of model3 (as a graph without disconnected nodes)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this:

```
input_model = model1()
output_model = model2()
model3 = Model([im1, im2], output_model(input_model([im1, im2])))
```

Then now `input_model` and `output_model`  are actual models from where you can predict, and you can use `model3` for training all layers in both models.